# How to filter the result in a view generated by RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise, rabl

I'm using RABL to render JSON.
I have these models:

1. `Project`
2. `Task`
3. `User`

The "show project" action should result in rendering of the details of the project **including a list of the Tasks in the Project, but only those who the user is permitted to view**.

So far, I've added all of the Tasks to the Project `show.rabl`, and it's working fine:

```
child tasks: :tasks do
  extends "task/show"
end
```

Is there a way to tell RABL to only render tasks that answer a given condition? -- I already have the logic for that in the controller, but I can't figure how to tell that to RABL...

**--update--**

I've figured a way to do that by adding a "code" section, passing in the project object and then building a hash from the visible tasks and rendering it. This works, but it is very ugly and defeats the purpose of using RABL in the first place.
It looks roughly like that:

```
code :tasks do |project|
  project.tasks.visible_by(current_user).inject([]){|arr, task| ...}
end
```

I'm sure my use case is not that unique. Is there a more straight-forward way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor the query into your model into a method called `specific_tasks` and then call something like this from RABL:

```
child specific_tasks: :tasks do
  extends "task/show"
end
```

Comment: In general I like this approach, however, I need to render something specific to the current_user, and this is usually not something I'd want the model to know about.